# jQuery UI datepicker accessibility fail

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jquery-ui-datepicker, wcag2.0

I'm using the jQuery UI datepicker widget (see [API docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)), but our accessibility compliance checker is complaining about the button image it inserts.  In particular it flags that the "buttonText" attribute gets used as both "alt" and "title" on the button image.

Input:

```
<input type='text' name='from' id='from' value=''>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#from' ).datepicker({
         buttonImageOnly:   true,
         buttonImage:       '/img/calendar_icon_20x20.png',
         buttonText:        'select date from calendar'
       ...
});
</script>
```

And the generated button object looks like this:

```
<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/img/calendar_icon_20x20.png"
    alt="select date from calendar"
  title="select date from calendar">
```

Is there some way to make the alt and title not be the same?

Comment: If you are concerned about accessibility, you should also check whether the [JQuery UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is keyboard accessible. I can't pick a date using the keyboard only. Please check [this datepicker](https://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_datepicker) instead.

Comment: Yes, I later found had to make some local mods to add keyboard access as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code in question, there is no direct way to do it:

```
inst.trigger = $(this._get(inst, "buttonImageOnly") ?
               $("<img/>").addClass(this._triggerClass)
                          .attr({ src: buttonImage, alt: buttonText, title: buttonText }) :
               $("<button type='button'</button>")
                          .addClass(this._triggerClass)
                          .html(!buttonImage ? buttonText : $("<img/>")
                          .attr({ src: buttonImage, alt: buttonText, title: buttonText })));
```

As the *buttonText* attribute is directly applied to both the *alt* and *title* properties.

Options:

1. Somehow change alt or title properties after the fact with
   JavaScript
2. Make a local variant of jquery-ui with an additional *buttonTitle* property *(arguably the correct choice if the changes would be accepted upstream)*
3. Make a local variant that hard-codes the title *(what my lazy self did)*

Comment: Do you have a demo of this anywhere? Is there a reason why the datepicker should be attached to an image instead of an input field?

Comment: The UI that people here are accustomed to is a text input with a picture of a calendar to the right of it and clicking on the calendar picture brings up the datepicker.  Other people could definitely want a different UI.